# if else statement gone bad

Tags: r

I get an error message when running this, is there anything that is blatently obvious to anyone?

```
 yo <-  function(x) {

      filt <- ddply(x, .(primer,day), summarise, count=sum(timepoints==0)) # this will tell you all primers that have a 0 hr time point by giveing a 1 in the count column



 if (any(filt$count) == 0)     { # this was the case once so I implemented this if else part

      filt <- filt[filt$count == 0,]
      include <-!(x$primer%in%filt$primer)&(x$day%in%filt$day) # all primers that have 0 hrs
      x <- x[include,] 
     ### for any given replicate, divide each timepoint by its zero hour 
     x <- ddply(x, .(primer),transform, foldInduction=realConc/realConc[timepoints==0])

}


  else {
x <- ddply(x, .(primer), transform, foldInduction=realConc/realConc[timepoints==0])
   }
  x[,-9]

  }
```

Comment: we can't replicate your problem without some sample data. update your question with the output from `dput(head(x))`

Comment: It might help to include the error message.

Comment: Is this really how your code looks?  Is there a reason for the weird spacing and indentation?

Comment: Also `any(filt$count) == 0` likely has a parens in the wrong place.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman you nailed it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [if/else constructs inside and outside functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724063/if-else-constructs-inside-and-outside-functions)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, placement of the curly braces.

You are encouraged to write

```
 if (cond) {
     code
 } else {
     more_code
 }
```

as the parser proceeds line-by-line -- unless you use something like `source()`, or parse as it is done when a package is built and files are consumed "whole" rather than line-by-line.

But as a general rule:  do not use the style your original question showed.

Comment: hmm..i don't think this will actually make a difference though, right?

Comment: It makes a difference for the if/else.  You need the else clause to start on the same line as the ending brace of the if statement.

Comment: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf also has a nice section (8.1.43) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright promoting my comments to an answer.

`any(filt$count) == 0` makes little sense.  Why?  Like all logical coercions in R, `any` will take the numbers that `filt$count` represents and return true if zero, 1 if nonzero.

```
> any(5)
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In any(5) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

However, once it's a logical, you then coerce it back to numeric by comparing it to an numeric.  So what your statement really does is see if any of `filt$count` are zero (in which case it returns `TRUE`), then negates that.

```
> any( c(5,6,7) )==0
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In any(c(5, 6, 7)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
> any( c(5,6,0) )==0
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In any(c(5, 6, 0)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
> any( c(0) )==0
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In any(c(0)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

Solution: don't do that.