# if/else constructs inside and outside functions

Tags: r, if-statement

When I look at R functions I often find the following structure:

```
f <- function(exp=T) {
  if (exp)
    a <- 1
  else
    a <- 2
}
f()
f(F)
```

This will run without error. But executing the inner function code throws an error as R probably assumes that the statement is finished after the first assignment `a <- 1` and cannot handle the following else.

```
exp=T
if (exp)
  a <- 1
else
  a <- 2
```

Now, this makes sense to me, but I still would like to understand why the behaviour of the executed code differs when executed inside or outside a function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It’s a consequence of using an interactive shell ([REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)) to run scripts:

After the first branch the shell has seen a complete statement so it assumes that you’re done typing. Unfortunately, R uses the same shell for interpreting scripts even if they are not typed in interactively – so even when you save the `if` statement to a file and `source` it (or pipe it into R) you will get the error on the `else` branch.

But the following will work just fine:

```
if (exp) a <- 1 else a <- 2
```

Here, the interpreter swallows the line and executes it.

In your function one would assume that the same applies – *and it does!* However, the function *itself* starts with an open brace in your case, so R has to read until it finds the matching closing brace. By contrast, take this function declaration:

```
f <- function (exp)
    if (exp)
        a <- 1
    else
        a <- 2
```

In R you can define functions without braces around the body. But the above code will fail for the same reason that the standalone `if` without braces fails. By contrast, if I had written the `if` on a single line this code would once again work.

Incidentally, your function uses an assignment to a variable that isn’t used. You can (should) do the following instead:

```
f <- function (exp) {
    if (exp)
        1
    else
        2
}
```

… and the same when using `if` inside the shell:

```
a <- if (exp) 1 else 2
```

because in R, `if` is an *expression* which returns a value.

Comment: I am not sure you explained why the multiline `if ... else ...` is interpreted as a single statement when it is inside the body of the function. It is because when you start typing `f <- function(exp=T){`, R is going to keep reading until the whole block is closed with a matching `}`. That will allow the interpreter to find that `else` is the continuation of the `if` started just above. Right?

Comment: @flodel Ah yes, I might need to make this clearer. But your conjecture is spot-on. And guess what happens when you remove the braces around the function body … ;-)

Answer (score 36):

**Executive Summary:**

There are only two ways for R to know that an else clause belongs to the if clause above it:

1. The entire if...else statement (and perhaps other statements as well) is enclosed in braces;
2. The word else appears on the same line as the end of the if clause.

**Evidence:**

The above discussion helped me, but I hope I can offer a useful quibble.  Yes, it is correct that

```
f <- function (exp)
    if (exp)
        1  
    else
        2
```

fails with the classic `Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"` message due to R's failure to keep reading past the 1.  Two ways have been correctly offered to make R keep reading past the 1:

```
f <- function (exp) {
    if (exp)
        1  
    else
        2
}
```

and

```
f <- function (exp) if (exp) 1 else 2
```

But there is a third way not yet mentioned---just move `else` up a line.  Thus, the following also works because R knows to keep reading past the 1:

```
f <- function (exp)
    if (exp)
        1  else
        2
```

I think the key point is to either brace the entire body of the function, or make sure the `else` occurs on the same line as the end of the if clause so that R knows to keep reading.  That's why the one-line solution works.  It is also why this works:

```
f <- function (exp)
    if (exp) {
        1
    } else
        2
```

But this fails:

```
f <- function (exp)
    if (exp) {
        1
    }  
    else
        2
```

And using the more standard bracing of the function body, this works too:

```
f <- function (exp) {
    if (exp) {
        1
    }  
    else
        2
}
```

But whether or not we are building a function is a red herring.  What matters is only braces and location of `else`.  Thus, these work:

```
{
    if (exp) {
        1
    }  
    else
        2
}


if (exp) {
    1
} else
    2
```

but this fails:

```
if (exp) {
    1
} 
else
    2
```

and to demonstrate my assertion 1 at the top, this works:

```
{
x <- 4
if (exp) 
    1
else
    2
}
```

Comment: yes!  Thank you for including more scenarios ...  I always use brackets but also always use a new line ... until R  :-p .