# if - else if - else statement and brackets

Tags: r, if-statement

I understand the usual way to write an "if - else if" statement is as follow:

```
if (2==1) {
  print("1")
} else if (2==2) {
  print("2")
} else {
  print("3")
}
```

or

```
if (2==1) {print("1") 
} else if (2==2) {print("2")
} else print("3")
```

On the contrary, If I write in this way

```
if (2==1) {
  print("1")
} 
else if (2==2) {
  print("2")
}
else (print("3"))
```

or this way:

```
if (2==1) print("1") 
else if (2==2) print("2")
else print("3")
```

the statement does NOT work. Can you explain me why `}` must precede `else` or `else if` in the same line? Are there any other way of writing the if-else if-else statement in R, especially without brackets?

Comment: When the initial `if` is followed by a compound expression (indicated by the `{}` pair) the parser by default is going to expect the expression followed by `else` to be compound as well. The only defined use of `else` is with compound expressions. This is even stated in the docs: `if(cond) cons.expr  else  alt.expr` where `cons.expr` and `alt.expr` are defined to be compound. As @Berry indicated, you can use the way R parses function definitions to work around this, but it'd be better to be consistent in bracket use (IMO).

Comment: also if you wrap the unusual if-else in brackets `{ bad if-else expr }` or in a function which is more common `function() { bad if-else expr}`, it will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected 'else' in "else" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865435/unexpected-else-in-else-error)

Comment: I find it a pity that 'Reformat Code' (in RStudio) does not format the else towards the right place. It could see this issue, IMHO.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

R reads these commands line by line, so it thinks you're done after executing the expression after the if statement. Remember, you can use `if` **without** adding `else`.

Your third example will work in a function, because the whole function is defined before being executed, so R *knows* it wasn't done yet (after `if() do`).

Comment: I tried it within a function and both my 3rd and 4th example works within the function. Thanks

Comment: This is mentioned in the R-inferno, section 8.1.43 btw.

Answer (score 14):

In R, also we have *ifelse()* function:

```
ifelse(1 < 0, "hello", "hi")
```

Output:

```
# [1] "hi"
```

Answer (score 2):

As  [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) has mentioned:

> When the initial if is followed by a compound expression (indicated by
>   the {} pair) the parser by default is going to expect the expression
>   followed by else to be compound as well. The only defined use of else
>   is with compound expressions.

In the statement `if(cond) cons.expr else alt.expr`, the `else` needs to be put after and in same line with the end `cons.expr' compound.

So if you want to have your code a better look without brackets, apply this way:

```
if (2==1) print("1") else 
   if (2==2) print("2") else 
      print("3")
```

Answer (score 0):

ifelse has tree parametes, first conditon, second true result and last false result.

```
y_pred = ifelse(prob_predict > 0.5,1,0)
```