# Subset a dataframe using if-conditions inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I'm trying to use this basic structure to address a data reshaping problem;

```
for(i in 1:5) {                           # Head of for-loop
  if(i < 4) {                             # First if-condition 
    if(i %in% seq(2, 10, 2)) {            # Second if-condition 
      print(i)                            # Some output
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer, although I'm discussing "dates" in this code they are a Julian date system, so they're not in POSIXct format and behave as integers.

I want to use a list of values ("dates") to find cases in a list "bydates" that meet 2 conditions, and write them to a new df. "bydates" has 2275 observations of 4 variables; NatalName, JStart, JEnd, FAM (format chr, num, num, chr).

for each value in "dates" (i) I want to assess if JStart < i, and if JEnd > i, and if both conditions are met to write to the lists df in the format i, NatalNAme, FAM.

This is one of my attempts, that I keep coming back to (I also tried functions, and ifelse and if_else, without success).

```
lists <- c() # create a blank variable to store the result

for(i in dates) 
        {if(bydates$Jstart <= i) {
                if(JEnd > i) {
                        lists <- as.df(i, bydates$FAM, bydates$NatalName)
        }
}
}
```

This returns "Error in if (bydates$Jstart <= i) { : the condition has length > 1"

I think this means more than one value in my "bydates" df meets the condition, which is  correct, but then does that mean I should be looping on "bydates" instead? I've spent more than a week researching this and I remain stuck. I'm also confused why I don't get the commonly reported "the condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used" error.

Any help very much appreciated.

EDIT: as requested by @Stefan, a snippet of the data using dput

```
> dput(dates[1:4])
c(744, 864, 984, 1224)
> dput(head(bydates))
structure(list(NatalName = c("AAN12", "AAN18", "AAN20", "ABI96", 
"ABR12", "ABR17"), Jstart = c(1113, 1178, 1203, 914, 1105, 1175
), JEnd = c(1158, 1180, -23053, 915, -23053, -23053), FAM = c("AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: you might want to look at how to construct `if()` statements/have multiple conditions in the same `if()`. maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261946/multiple-if-statements-in-r) will help.

Comment: You are most likely having the issue that `if` does not work on vectors, try replacing them with `ifelse()`. See [here](https://www.statology.org/r-condition-has-length-1-only-first-element-will-be-used/) for more info.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code and data it's difficult to be sure but I suspect you don't need a loop nor `if`. You probabably only need to subset your data with a logical vector.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `if` is not vectorized. It is meant to be used to control the flow of your script, i.e. if **one** condition is met do A. Put differently, `if` requires that the condition returns a logical vector of length 1, whereas your condition `bydates$Jstart <= i` returns a vector  of length > 1, i.e. a length equal to the number of rows in your dataset. Hence, you get an error.

While there is the vectorized `ifelse`, overall an `if` is not needed. What you are trying to achieve is to subset a dataset and this could easier be achieved by using e.g.

```
bydates[bydates$Jstart <= i & bydates$JEnd > i,]
```

Also, as you want a list of datasets you may consider to use `lapply` instead of a `for` loop:

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of using `lapply` (and `subset` for the subsetting) based on some fake example data may look like so:

```r
bydates <- data.frame(
  JStart = seq(as.Date("2022-01-03"), as.Date("2022-01-12"), by = "day"),
  JEnd = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-10"), by = "day"),
  FAM = letters[1:10],
  NatalName = LETTERS[1:10]
)

dates <- c(as.Date("2022-01-05"), as.Date("2022-01-10"))

lapply(dates, function(i) {
  bydates$i <- i
  subset(bydates, JStart >= i & JEnd < i, c(i, FAM, NatalName))
})
#> [[1]]
#>            i FAM NatalName
#> 3 2022-01-05   c         C
#> 4 2022-01-05   d         D
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            i FAM NatalName
#> 8 2022-01-10   h         H
#> 9 2022-01-10   i         I
```

Comment: thanks @stefan, This makes a lot of sense, and I do see what you mean. However, I'm not sure this quite works; using your code on my data, I get ; 
Error in `x[r, vars, drop = drop]`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Location 744 doesn't exist.
ℹ There are only 4 columns.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. 
Warning message:
In dates$i <- i : Coercing LHS to a list
As I said in my original post, here my dates are actually in Julian format and 744 is the first value in the list. Even if I add dates<- as.list(dates) I still get the error less the last warning

Comment: Hm. Could you provide a snippet of `bydates` and `dates` via `dput(), e.g. type `dput(head(bydates))` into the console and copy the output as an edit to your post and similarly using e.g. `dput(dates[1:5])`. For more on `dput()` see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution using purrr, with the help of a friend;

```
    library(purrr)

    setdates<-function(y){
    
    bydates %>%
            filter(Jstart<= y & JEnd >y) %>%
            mutate(Date = y) %>%
            select(NatalName, FAM, Date) %>%
            arrange(FAM)}

    famdat<-map_df(dates, setdates)
```

My problem was that I was trying to integrate dates before setting up a function handling the data manipulation. In case this helps anyone else....