# R: IF object is TRUE then assign object NOT WORKING

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write a very basic IF statement in R and am stuck. I thought I'd find someone with the same problem, but I cant. Im sorry if this has been solved before.

I want to check if a variable/object has been assigned, IF TRUE I want to execute a function that is part of a R-package. First I wrote

```
FileAssignment <- function(x){
  if(exists("x")==TRUE){
    print("yes!")
    x <- parse.vdjtools(x)
  } else { print("Nope!")}
}
```

I assign a filename as x

```
FILENAME <- "FILENAME.txt"
```

I run the function

```
FileAssignment(FILENAME)
```

I use print("yes!") and print("Nope!") to check if the IF-Statement works, and it does. However, the `parse.vdjtools(x)` part is not assigned. Now I tested the same IF-statement outside of the function:

```
if(exists("FILENAME1")==TRUE){
  FILENAME1 <- parse.vdjtools(FILENAME1)
}
```

This works. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724063/if-else-constructs-inside-and-outside-functions) that it might be because the function uses `{}` and the if-statement does too. So I should remove the brackets from the if-statement.

```
FileAssignment <- function(x){
  if(exists("x")==TRUE)
    x <- parse.vdjtools(x)
   else { print("Nope!")
}
```

Did not work either.

I thought it might be related to the specific `parse.vdjtools(x)` function, so I just tried assigning a normal value to x with `x <- 20`. Also did not work inside the function, however, it does outside.

Comment: Side point, take a look at `?missing` as an alternative to `exists()` in this case.

Comment: It’s completely unclear what you’re actually trying to accomplish. At any rate, as a side-note, it makes no sense to test a logical object against `TRUE`. Remove the `==TRUE` part, it’s nonsensical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really know what you are trying to acheive, but I wpuld say that the  use of `exists` in this context is wrong. There is no way that the x cannot exist inside the function. See this example

```
# All this does is report if x exists
f <- function(x){
       if(exists("x"))
         cat("Found x!", fill = TRUE)
     }

f()
f("a")
f(iris)

# All will be found!
```

Investigate `file.exists` instead? This is vectorised, so a vector of files can be investigated at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The question that you are asking is less trivial than you seem to believe. There are two points that should be addressed to obtain the desired behavior, and especially the first one is somewhat tricky:

1. As pointed out by @NJBurgo and @KonradRudolph the variable `x` will always exist within the function since it is an argument of the function. In your case the function `exists()` should therefore not check whether the variable `x` is defined. Instead, it should be used to verify whether **a variable with a name corresponding to the character string** stored in `x` exists.

   This is achieved by using a combination of `deparse()` and
   `substitute()`:

   ```
   if (exists(deparse(substitute(x)))) { …
   ```
2. Since `x` is defined only within the scope of the function, the superassignment operator `<<-`  would be required to make a value assigned to `x` visible outside the function, as suggested by @thothai. However, functions should not have such side effects. Problems with this kind of programming include possible conflicts with another variable named `x` that could be defined in a different context outside the function body, as well as a lack of clarity concerning the operations performed by the function.

   A better way is to **return** the value instead of assigning it to a variable.

Combining these two aspects, the function could be rewritten like this:

```
FileAssignment <- function(x){      
  if (exists(deparse(substitute(x)))) {
    print("yes!")
    return(parse.vdjtools(x))
  } else {
    print("Nope!")
    return(NULL)}
}
```

In this version of the function, the scope of `x` is limited to the function body and the function has no side effects. The return value of `FileAssignment(a)` is  either `parse.vdjtools(a)` or `NULL`, depending on whether `a` exists or not. 
Outside the function, this value can be assigned to `x` with

```
x <- FileAssignment(a)
```