# R Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm having a simple R code which returns Error: unexpected 'else' in "else":

```
if(1==1)
{
    x = 1
}
else
{
    x = 2
}
```

Can someone please explain how thats possible?

Its a different case than question [Unexpected 'else' in "else" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865435/unexpected-else-in-else-error) because there the problem appears to be caused by a nested else while here it is unnested.

Comment: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13885942/6779509) for a good explaination of `if` interpretation in R

Comment: Put the `else` on the same line as the first `}`

Comment: This question was helpful and should be marked positively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

typing else on the same line as the closing } solves this problem:

```
    if(1==1)
{
  x = 1
} else
{
  x = 2
}
```